# Write INSERT INTO VALUES(:P1_item)

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I want to write down what value I have in the form, in another table, but it does not work out what is wrong ?? I did a dynamic action before the create button

```
INSERT INTO SEC_SEALING_STATUS (NAME_OBJ,SEALING) 
VALUES (:P7_NAME_OBJ,'Ні');
```

Answer (score 0):

When invoking PL/SQL in a dynamic action, you need to send the relevant values from your browser to the database using the 'Page items to submit' attribute.

In your case, you should see P7_NAME_OBJ listed in the attribute, otherwise the value will be null, or whatever it was last time session state was updated.

Answer (score 0):

- remove the dinamix action
- set the button to 'submit page'
- create a process pl/sql with your insert code.